# how to array value convert in dictionary objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to convert an array into a dictionary in Objective-C language?

This is the array:

> [{"1":"2"}, {"2":"3"}]

But I want :

> {"1":"2", "2":"3"}

Please help me, I am a new iPhone developer.

Comment: Can you tell us something more about how the array is defined?  The code that declares and fills it?

Comment: i suggest you to read some basic of objective-c. there are a lots of tutorial available on internet. [link 1](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary)

Comment: You need to show what you've tried and show what it did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want to combine an array of dictionaries into a single dictionary.

```
NSArray *array =  @[@{@"1":@"2"},@{@"2":@"3"}];

NSMutableDictionary *result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array)
{
     [result addEntriesFromDictionary:dict];
}

/*
result = {
  1 = 2;
  2 = 3;
}
*/
```

Comment: You might prefer to use `addEntriesFromDictionary:`

Answer (score 1):

Where did your data come from?  The easiest way to "convert" the above is to simply create a single dictionary in the first place.

Otherwise:

```
NSMutableDictionary* newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary* oldDict in sourceArray) {
    [newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:oldDict];
}
```